# Python TeamCity Test Runner does not run setUpClass and tearDownClass

Tags: python, teamcity, python-unittest

I am using TeamCity Test Runner for (obviously) running python tests on TeamCity.
The things is, that for some reason, When I run the test from TeamCity - setUpClass and tearDownClass cannot be called.

When I run locally, everything works just fine.

### How can I fix that?

edit: Is it possible that this is because the remote machine python is 2.6.5 version and mine is 2.7.9 ?

Comment: Are you able to run the same build on the same machine as the TeamCity agent is running? See the related [guideline](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common+Problems#CommonProblems-BuildfailsorbehavesdifferentlyinTeamCitybutnotlocally).

Answer (score 0):

SetUpClass and TearDownClass are available to python as from 2.7.*.
If one wants to use SetUpClass and TearDownClass on older version of Python it can be done by using unittest2.